# Premiere Pro: Multiple bit depths in same timeline?

Tags: premiere, video-recording

all...

I want to do a two camera shoot but one camera records 10-bit 4:2:2 and the other 8-bit 4:2:2. Can I put clips from both cameras on the same timeline in Premiere Pro?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: You can. Premiere Pro handles diffrent files, codecs and settings quite good. The question is more about quality. Do you want to export 4:2:2? Also, all... and Steve isn't necessary. You should only write the question

Comment: +1 "yes you can," as others have said.  Only other advice is try to get the look of both cameras as close to "correct" as possible on set (remember to set WB, don't let any color channel get to 100% brightness, add light to dark areas if you need to).  Then, if you need to perform any adjustments in post to get the cameras to match, you'll see that it's easier to make the 10bit one match the 8bit one than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Premiere can handle different codecs, dimensions, frame rates, and bit depths etc. just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mix almost anything within one timeline in PP. The only difference would be the 8-bit won't hold as much data so you have to be mindful in how much colour adjustment you throw at it. It's best to edit the 8bit clip and match the 10bit to it (as it can take more) than the other way round.